# Conditional meltdown

Tags: conditionals

I have a conditional which is the following:

```
{if '{current_time format="%H%i"}' >= '0000' AND '{current_time format="%H%i"}' <= '1300'}
    <a href="{path="speisekarten"}#mittagskarte">{navi_speisekarten}</a> 
{if:else}
    <a href="{path="speisekarten"}#abendkarte">{navi_speisekarten}</a>
{/if}
```

This works well. But I need an additional function: If there is no entry in the Channel "mittagskarte" show `<a href="{path="speisekarten"}#abendkarte">{navi_speisekarten}</a>` even if it's between `0000` and `1300`

How do I write this? This melts my brain. I tried a few things mostly ending up in a parsing errors.

The conditional is not inside a Channel Tag.

Thank you

Comment: +1 for an awesome title

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am not sure if i got it right but couldn't you simply wrap the conditionals in a {exp:channel:entries} tag and use the no_results to display your link?

Perhaps not the most optimal way but it should get you what you want.

Something like this would do...

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="mittagskarte" limit="1" dynamic="no" disable="categories|category_fields|custom_fields|member_data|pagination"}
    {if '{current_time format="%H%i"}' >= '0000' AND '{current_time format="%H%i"}' <= '1300'}
        <a href="{path="speisekarten"}#mittagskarte">{navi_speisekarten}</a> 
    {if:else}
        <a href="{path="speisekarten"}#abendkarte">{navi_speisekarten}</a>
    {/if}
    {if no_results}
        <a href="{path="speisekarten"}#abendkarte">{navi_speisekarten}</a>
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Update:
@foamcow mentions switchee, the same developer also has a plugin called [IfElse](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ifelse) which enables you to parse advanced conditionals early.
But i don't think you would need to since {if no_results} should be the only thing parsed in the channel-loop since the time-conditional, being an advanced conditional, is parsed later.

Comment: No probs. :D Would you mind marking this as answered?

Answer (score 2):

Put your channel check outside the time check.

In pseudo-code, something like..

```
If no entry in channel mittagskarte

    show link to abendkarte

else

    if time is between 0000 and 13000
        show first link
    else
        show second link
    end time check

end channel check
```

So you'll need a channel entries tagpair in there in order to test whether there are any entries in mittagskarte

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="mittagskarte" dynamic="off" limit="1"}
    {if no_results}
        <a href="{path="speisekarten"}#abendkarte">{navi_speisekarten}</a>
    {/if}

    {if '{current_time format="%H%i"}' >= '0000' AND '{current_time format="%H%i"}' <= '1300'}
        <a href="{path="speisekarten"}#mittagskarte">{navi_speisekarten}</a> 
    {if:else}
        <a href="{path="speisekarten"}#abendkarte">{navi_speisekarten}</a>
    {/if}       
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I think you could probably use a couple of add-ons here if you really wanted to. I'm sure that Croxton's Switchee, or another "advanced conditionals" add on might help and you may even find another that will let you test the entry count in a channel without the tag pair. It should be simple enough write a plugin for that if one doesn't exist.

EDIT
As pointed out by Kim, the no_results tag would be better than checking count.

Comment: This approach seems logic to me. But when I implement this the link doesn't show up at all when ´channel="mittagskarte"´ is empty. I tried to replace {if count != 0 } with {if title == ""} but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: See my update and use no_results rather than count - as per Kim's answer. See if that works.